# How to pass json data to a meteor template

Tags: javascript, json, templates, meteor, http-get

I'm trying to pass data from a json rest api to a meteor template

I get the JSON from a HTTP GET like this:

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {

    Meteor.http.call("GET", "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed", function (err, result){
        console.log(result.content);
    })
}

if (Meteor.is_server) {

}
```

and i can see the JSON data in the browser console

how can i pass the data to a template?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways, depending on where you make the call and what packages you use. The simplest one is to use session and a helper:

```
HTTP.get(..., function(err, result) {
  Session.set('httpResult', result);
});

Template.myTemplate.json = function() {
  return Session.get('httpResult');
};


<template name="myTemplate">
  {{json.property}}
  {{#with json}}
    {{property}}
    {{otherProperty}}
    {{lotsOfProperties}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: thanks @HubertOG it didn't work 
i can get any data from the URL

Comment: This works to render a json object's properties like this, you might have an error elsewhere @Hugo.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to save the results in a variable and use a #with in your template.

```
 Meteor.http.call("GET", "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed", function (err, result){
    my_json = result.content;
})
```

template:

```
<template name="json_data">
   {{#with my_jason}}
      ...
   {{/with}}
```

Comment: Thanks @ErezHochman but it didn't work
the json is stored in the variable but dont show nothing in the browser

Comment: add "Session.get('init')" to the "my_json" helper and "Session.set('init',True)" to the http.call callback.
the Template is drawen before the http.call is made and since it's not a reactive template it does not refresh itself. calling Session.get from withing a template will bind that Session as depepndecy for the template (even if you do nothing with the data you get from Session.get, it's enough to call it.